# Wordpress Meta_Query open close time

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, post-meta

I am trying to make a filter with open and closed checkbox using Meta_Query.
The value of metadatas is UNIX time, so the value of $opening_time and $closing_time is number like this - 234321543.
It only works without $status_2, $opening_time_2, $closing_time_2. 
I think that something wrong with time logic.
How can i get it worked?

```
    $status =         'opening_hours_monday_day_status';
    $opening_time =   'opening_hours_monday_opening_time';
    $closing_time =   'opening_hours_monday_closing_time';
    $status_2 =       'opening_hours_monday2_day_status';
    $opening_time_2 = 'opening_hours_monday2_opening_time';
    $closing_time_2 = 'opening_hours_monday2_closing_time';
    $current_time =   strtotime('2016-01-01 ' . current_time('h:i a'));
    $element_filter_arr = array();
             if ($timings == 'open') {
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'key' => $status,
                        'value' => 'on',
                        'compare' => '=',
                    );
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'key' => $opening_time,
                        'value' => $current_time,
                        'compare' => '<=',
                    );
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'key' => $closing_time,
                        'value' => $current_time,
                        'compare' => '>=',
                    );
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'key' => $status_2,
                        'value' => 'on',
                        'compare' => '=',
                    );
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'key' => $opening_time_2,
                        'value' => $current_time,
                        'compare' => '<=',
                    );
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'key' => $closing_time_2,
                        'value' => $current_time,
                        'compare' => '>=',
                    );
                } else if ($timings == 'close') {
                    $element_filter_arr[] = array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => $status,
                            'value' => 'off',
                            'compare' => '=',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => $opening_time,
                            'value' => $current_time,
                            'compare' => '>',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => $closing_time,
                            'value' => $current_time,
                            'compare' => '<',
                        ),
                    );
                }

$args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => "-1",
                    'post_type' => 'shop',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'fields' => 'ids',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        $element_filter_arr,
                    ),
```

Comment: Take `$current_time` as `time();` and have a try

Comment: And are you sure about this value `234321543`, its `06/05/1977 @ 1:19am (UTC)`

Comment: the number 234321543 i wrote randomly just for example.

Comment: Have you updated `$current_time` as `time();` and tried ?

Comment: Yes , i tried but same result.

Comment: i spent 2 days trying to get it worked, anyone can help me?

Comment: One more thing, We only need time to compare, and we are comparing with date, Can you also give me values that are in opening and close times

Comment: Nair, the values of opening and closing variables are unix time.

Comment: What are you trying to fetch, To pass date and time and get posts which are opened at that time ? Am I correct ?

Comment: yes, correct.If i remove  $status_2, $opening_time_2 and $closing_time_2  it works well.

Comment: Hey do you want to look into both dates? or any one of them? You have to use `'relation' => 'OR',` or `'relation' => 'AND',` as per your requirements

Comment: i have open/close time list like this : 01:00 pm -  12:00 am || 12:00 am - 02 am, after it is converted to unix time , open1 = 2345234 closing1 = 231425 and open2= 2343453 closing2 =3425435 ,  i have filter checkbox showing open/close shops, it works only with one of them either with only open1 etc. or with only open2 etc.

Comment: First of all try my answer only for open condition and tell me whether it is working for you or not ?

Comment: it is not working, i get 500: Internal Error

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this for open condition

```
if ($timings == 'open') {       
   $meta_query_args = array(
     'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => $status,
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $opening_time,
            'value' => $current_time,
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $closing_time,
            'value' => $current_time,
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
    array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => $status2,
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
            ),
        array(
            'key' => $opening_time2,
            'value' => $current_time,
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
    array(
        'key' => $closing_time2,
        'value' => $current_time,
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
    ),
    );
   }
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

Comment: internal 500 error ? Its just an example. I hope you added `post_type` to this meta query

Comment: Thank you , bro , for trying to help me, but i have already resolved it .

Comment: You can post you answer, So that it may be helpful for others

Comment: I just divided it into two blocks and used if(intval(date('H'))